# Can I use multiple methods in the same action?

Tags: java, json, jsp, extjs, struts2

I am using Struts 2 (2.5.10.1) with struts2-json-plugin-2.5.10.1. On my page I have a grid using ExtJs 4.2.2 that will be populated with projects, each row will have two actions: `edit` and `delete`.

The problem is that I have encountered: if I try to use multiple methods from the same action to do all the above, when I try to populate the grid I get no JSON response. Is what i am trying to do even possible ? (The `edit` and `delete` functionalities are not yet implemented)

**Here is my `struts.xml`:**

```xml
   <package name="admin" extends="json-default">
    
    <action name="requestProjectData"
        class="administrator.ACTION_ProjectsGrid"
        method="requestProjectData">
        <result type="json" >
            <param name="root">projectData</param>
        </result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="requestDeleteProject"
        class="administrator.ACTION_ProjectsGrid"
        method="deleteProject">
        <result type="json" >
            <param name="root">success</param>
        </result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="requestEditProject"
        class="administrator.ACTION_ProjectsGrid"
        method="editProject">
        <result type="json" >
            <param name="root">success</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

**Here is my Action class:**

```java
public class ACTION_ProjectsGrid extends ActionSupport {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<Project> projectData;
private boolean success;

public void requestProjectData()
{
    ProjectManager pm = new ProjectManager();
    List<Project> listOfProjects = pm.getAllProjects();
    projectData = listOfProjects;
}

public void deleteProject()
{
    success = true;
}

public void editProject()
{
    success = true;
}

public List<Project> getProjectData() {
    return projectData;
}

public void setProjectData(List<Project> projectData) {
    this.projectData = projectData;
}

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}
```

}

**And my JSP page:**

```xml
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.define('Project', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [ 'projectId', 'projectName' ]
    });
    
    var projStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Project',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            pageParam: false,
            startParam: false,
            limitParam: false,
            noCache: false,
            url: 'requestProjectData',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });
    
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        store: projStore,
        width: 641,
        height: 300,
        title: 'Projects',
        columns: [
            {
                text: 'ID',
                width: 80,
                dataIndex: 'projectId'
            },
            {
                text: 'Project Name',
                width: 80,
                dataIndex: 'projectName'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                width: 80,
                items: [{
                    icon: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/JavaScript/extjs/resources/user_edit.png',
                    tooltip: 'Edit',
                    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                        var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'requestDeleteProject',
                            disableCaching: false,
                            params: {
                                projectId: rec.get("projectId").toString(), 
                                },
                            success: function(response)
                            {
                                grid.getStore().load();
                            }
                            });
                        }
                }]
            }
        ]
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. For this solution to work, all methods have to be created like the execute method. After I changed the return type to String and returned ActionSupport.SUCCESS, the json response appeared. But I still do not know if this solution is correct or I am breaking some rules, can anyone explain this to me ?

Comment: That's one of the whole points of Struts 2: actions should return strings (it's the command pattern). The S2 docs discuss this in some detail. (Technically there are other options than strings, but I suspect at this point, you should stick w/ basic operations.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
       url: 'requestDeleteProject',
       disableCaching: false,
       params: {
            projectId: rec.get("projectId").toString(), 
       },
       success: function(response){
            grid.getStore().load();
       }
  });}
```

Inside that part you making your request... You should decode  the "response" inside the sucess and after it load the data to your store; making `grid.getStore().load()`
You are making another Request you want is something like

```
var json = Ext.decode(response.wtv..);
```

and then you want to load the grid's store like

```
grid.getStore().loadData(json);
```

soo like

```
success: function(response){
    var json = Ext.decode(response.wtv..); 
    grid.getStore().loadData(json);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my problem is when i try to launch the jsp page, at the requestProjectData, i get no json response to load to the grid. I stated that the edit and delete functionalities are not yet implemented, thats why this delete request is not quite correct.

Comment: Yes, pardon me; i see i missed the point;
Sadly i don't know struts i use spring; 
But in Spring i have to do the annotation of @requestMapping("Controller/service") and that gives me the url; you are sure that is correct on your controller / server side?
There is a perfect way to test it, If you don't know this tool **Insonmia** you should! Perfect for testing json services

Comment: Well, the request works because i see that the method was called in my log from the server side, but no response is sent. Thank you for that tool tip.

Answer (score 0):

If you define an action that is mapped to the action class' method, the method should return either `String` or `Result`. The `ActionSupport` class provides you the default implementation for the action class.

Beside that, it implements a lot of interfaces that involve additional functionality via interceptors. One of this interfaces is `Action`. It is a functional interface that has only one method `execute()` which is invoked by default if no method is mapped to the action.

The value that is returned from the action method is a *result code*. This code or `Result` is necessary for Struts to proceed with the response after the action was executed. Thus the result code is returned to the invoker (`ActionInvocation`) which finds and executes a result with the same name defined in the action configuration. The default result `name` is `Action.SUCCESS` or `ActionSupport.SUCCESS` that you can return from the action. There should be result in the action  configuration that implicitly or explicitly define a result with the name `"success"`.

The `"success"` result is defined by default in your configuration, because it's missing `name` attribute. So to execute this result you should return `"success"`, or `Action.SUCCESS`, or `ActionSupport.SUCCESS` that are the same string.

---

See more in the [Result Configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/result-configuration.html).

> When an action class method completes, it returns a `String`. The
> value of the String is used to select a result element. An action
> mapping will often have a set of results representing different
> possible outcomes. A standard set of result tokens are defined by the
> `ActionSupport` base class. Predefined result names
>
> ```
> String SUCCESS = "success";
> String NONE    = "none";
> String ERROR   = "error";
> String INPUT   = "input";
> String LOGIN   = "login";
> ```
>
> Of course, applications can define other result tokens to match
> specific cases.

---